# Stop automatic downloading on fetch request in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, download, fetch

I am working on a react app for face detection using picojs library that needs a binary model file in client side to run its detection algorithm. It works fine and detect the face.

The problem is when I use fetch api to import the binary model file (in page load), the browser  starts to download it automatically,

Here's the code

```
import faceModel from "./faceModel" // a binary model file without type
import pico from "./pico.js"

fetch(faceModel).then(response => {
    response.arrayBuffer().then(function (buffer) {
        const bytes = new Int8Array(buffer)
        ...
    })
})
```

How can I stop automatic downloading of the binary model file?

Is there another way to import the file?

Comment: End user doesn't need the file, It has to be cached on browser @JaromandaX

Comment: and how does "end user" differ from "browser"? I think I misunderstand everything you're saying ... fetch doesn't save the file to end users computer as a file, it loads it in the browser - caching is up to the browser settings

Comment: Imagine you open a web page that contains a canvas for your webcam input. it has to detect your face when you click a button, you don't want it to give you a binary file download window when you click that button. Am I clear? @JaromandaX

Comment: what is the binary file? why are you fetching it in your code? what is its purpose?

Comment: `The problem is when I use fetch api to import the binary model file (in page load), the browser starts to download it automatically. How can I stop automatic downloading of the binary model file` - this reads like ... "*when I use a hammer to bash myself over the head, it hurts, how can I stop it from hurting*"

Comment: I now it's wrong and thats why I'm asking question!! Let me simplify it: I want to use picojs face detection library in react. So how would you do that?